# Grub Rescue even after fix

Tags: grub2, system, grubrescue

I can get back to my OS by using the following commands, but every time I reboot the grub rescue screen comes back:

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt5)/boot/grub (edited)
insmod normal
normal
```

No matter what I do to the grub configs, nothing changes. I've tried to remake the config and edit the config manually but I haven't accomplished anything. What should I do?

OS Pop OS Latest Version
I have tried: update-grub, grub-mkconfig, grub-install

not sure if I have to uninstall grub first

Comment: Please provide OS & release details, and what commands you attempted to use to repair your system?  Did you just modify files without executing or re-install them to grub stage 0 (ie. they'll only take effect after next kernel upgrade for your *unstated* OS)

Comment: @guiverc added the information, but am not sure what you mean by reinstalling them to grub stage 0. I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use the Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu & flavors are the many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: Pop OS is not a version of Ubuntu; refer https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours for *flavors* of Ubuntu.  Pop OS does not use Ubuntu kernels, some releases of Pop OS boot differently to Ubuntu (esp. *live*, Ubuntu is built for many architectures; and work is done to keep all architectures booting the same for each release; Pop OS does not follow Ubuntu in this regard; so boot processes differ between Ubuntu & Pop OS for many recent releases, esp. regards *live* media). Pop OS also use *testing* grade packages, available for Ubuntu too - but not default in Ubuntu which strives for *stability*.

Comment: Grub stage 0 sits on the MBR, the first sector of the disk reserved for that purpose which is outside of the partition layout (ie. *formats don't touch it as you format partitions usually*).  The MBR is little more than a pointer really, telling `grub` where to load later stages of the code that pull up the menu; if the pointer is wrong though - you'll find yourself is Grub Rescue which is really limited as it's only 512 bytes of code (*the rest of the code couldn't be found as pointer was invalid*).  You're not using a Ubuntu system though; it differs rather significantly here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I don't know what's causing it, the way to fix it (for me) was by following the first answer on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232730/grub-not-loading-config-file-or-booting-into-linux-automatically) answer, which worked well. This problem is repeatable. I hope this helps someone.